# tensor product of ideal $I$ and $R/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I$ an ideal. View $I$ and $R/I$ as $R$-module. Then I want to know why $I \otimes R/I=I/I^{2}$.

I know there is a property in many books that $R/B \otimes C=C/BC$. But when I get down to element level, let $a \in I$, $b \in R/I$, then $a\otimes b=1\otimes ab=1\otimes 0=0$.

Where is the problem in this calculation?

Comment: well, just at a glance $1\notin I$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, this comes from the fact that $R/I \otimes_R M = M/IM$, applied to $M = I$ as an $R$-module. Concretely, the map
$$
[r] \times i \in R/I \times i \mapsto [r\cdot i] \in I/I^2
$$
is bilinear and $R$-balanced, hence induces a map
$$
[r]\otimes i \in R/I \otimes I \mapsto [ri] \in I/I^2.
$$

It is surjective, since $[a]$ is the image of $[1] \otimes a$. Moreover, if $[ri] = 0$, then $ri = \sum c_jd_j$ with $c_j,d_j \in I$ and

$$
[r] \otimes i = [1] \otimes ri = \sum_{j} [1] \otimes c_jd_j = \sum_j
[c_j] \otimes [d_j] = 0.$$

Hence the map is also mono, thus an iso.

The problem with your calculation is that your are passing coefficients from one side to the other in the wrong way: we have $[r] \otimes si = [sr] \otimes i$ for each $s \in R$. Not every element of $I$ is of the form $si$. We can't write $[r] \otimes a = [ar] \otimes 1$ because $1 \not \in I$, unless $I = R$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the step $a \otimes b$ to $1 \otimes ab$, because it's only valid when 1 is an element of $I$.

However if 1 were in $I$, then $R / I$ would be zero, aligning with your calculation.